# Prevent accidental double-click on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main page with a button that opens an overlay with item details that consist of several buttons *(eg. one with phone number)*.

My issue is that when user accidentally doubles clicks on the main page button, the first click will be corrected on the main page but the second click may point to the button with a phone number from the overlay that was opened with the first click. So the user is immediately forwarded to phone App, although he/she wanted to open just the overlay.

Safari has this behaviour covered but the issue is present in Chrome.

The only solution that comes to my mind is setTimeout to all buttons on the overlay. Is there a better way to handle such issue?

*P.S. It's not possible to move overlay buttons so their position is not similar with the main page button.*

Comment: One idea would be to add an animation to the opening of the dialog, and only actually enable the buttons after finished. I think less than half a second would be enough to prevent this situation but might be not too long to affect user experience otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do it with a timeout

```
//onOverlayOpen
this.overlay.classList.add('overlay--blocked');
setTimeout(() => {
    this.overlay.classList.remove('overlay--blocked');
}, 350);

//CSS
.overlay--blocked {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on ondblclick (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/ondblclick) to return false but it seems more like a UX problem where your buttons are exactly at the same position. 
Though if the user manages to click two buttons in a row it’s probably not considered a proper double click so the first solution might not work.

I would really suggest to move the second button to another position within the modal or to move the modal itself.

Comment: The UX thing is that the main page button is across whole mobile screen. As example the button in overlay is fixed 200px from top. So the issue happens when user is on the main page and is scrolled to a certain point (200px from top) where position of main button == position of button in overlay, ie. the button cannot be moved since this situation would still happen (but on different position).

Comment: AND GlobalEventHandlers.ondblclick unfortunately doesn't have support for Chrome on mobile

Comment: There is not really something you can do except changing the ux imho. It seems to be a super edgy case as well.
One less than ideal could also be to add a confirmation box after the click on the second button so that people can undo their mistake by clicking cancel